# How to get rid of inner dot filled with deeper colour in geom_point in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, pca

I don't want that smaller, inner, deeper coloured points in the geom point in the graph. How do I get rid of it? I tried playing around with shapes but nothing happened.

```
library(stats)
library(ggfortify)
sp1 <- rnorm(72, mean = 4, 1)
sp2 <- rnorm(72, mean = 2, 1)
sp3 <- rnorm(72, mean = 3, 1)
sp4 <- rnorm(72, mean = 9, 1)
temp <- rnorm(72, mean = 20, 5)
season <- rep(c("Summer", "Autumn","Winter", "Spring"), each = 18)

sp.abd <- data.frame(sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, season, temp)

pca_res <- prcomp(sp.abd[,-c(5,6)], scale. = TRUE)

autoplot(pca_res,
         loadings = TRUE, loadings.colour = 'blue',
         loadings.label = TRUE, loadings.label.size = 3) + 
  theme_classic() + geom_point(aes(color = sp.abd$season), size = 6, alpha = 0.5) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = rainbow(12,s = 0.6, start = 0, end = 0.7, rev = TRUE))
```

[image]

Following Randy's answer below I try to replicate it for colouring by temp (a gradient here)

```
autoplot(pca_res, sp.abd, color  = temp, 
         loadings = TRUE, loadings.colour = 'blue',
         loadings.label = TRUE, loadings.label.size = 3)  + 
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "white", mid = "cyan", high = "dodgerblue4", na.value = NA)
```

It generates just a gray plot. Only if I call colour outside the autoplot command does it use the scale_colour_gradient2 option. But this is still with the dots

[image]

```
autoplot(pca_res, size = 6, alpha. = 0.5,
         loadings = TRUE, loadings.colour = 'blue',
         loadings.label = TRUE, loadings.label.size = 3)  + geom_point(aes(colour = sp.abd$temp)) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "white", mid = "cyan", high = "dodgerblue4", na.value = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: your `season` is not defined

Comment: Please indicate which packages you're using for those functions - like, `prcomp()` is from `stats` and `autoplot()` from `ggplot2`? Asking because when I'm trying to run your code, I get error `Objects of type prcomp not supported by autoplot`

Comment: try passing `size = 0` from `autoplot` → `autoplot.prcomp` (in `ggfortify`) → `gg.biplot`

Comment: I don’t think this question depends at all on the `vegan` package, so it would be good to remove `library(vegan)` from the question. There is other stuff in the code that could be removed to make the question simpler, too (`theme_classic()`, `scale_color_manual()`, etc.).

Comment: Strangely, I still get points with `size=0` but `size=-1` seems to do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `autoplot.prcomp` (the `autoplot` method for `prcomp` objects as specified by `ggfortify`) already handles making the points without a `geom_point()` call, so you can put the color mapping, point size, and point opacity inside `autoplot`:

```
library(stats)
library(ggfortify)
sp1 <- rnorm(72, mean = 4, 1)
sp2 <- rnorm(72, mean = 2, 1)
sp3 <- rnorm(72, mean = 3, 1)
sp4 <- rnorm(72, mean = 9, 1)
season <- rep(c("Summer", "Autumn","Winter", "Spring"), each = 18)
sp.abd <- data.frame(sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, season)
pca_res <- prcomp(sp.abd[,-5], scale. = TRUE)

autoplot(pca_res,
         ################
         # Add this stuff
         data = sp.abd, 
         color = 'season',
         size=6, alpha=.5,
         ################
         loadings = TRUE, loadings.colour = 'blue',
         loadings.label = TRUE, loadings.label.size = 3) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = rainbow(12,s = 0.6, start = 0, end = 0.7, rev = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks! But it dosen't work for if I'm trying to colour by continous variable `+ 
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "white", mid = "cyan", high = "dodgerblue4", na.value = NA)` I'll update the question